# Why does the handler method not get found?

Tags: java, rest, servlets

I want to expose a simple REST API besides my GWT WebApplication using `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController`. I therefore added another servlet to my **web.xml** and mapped it to `/app/restapi/*`:

```
<!-- ... -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>xsrf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.XsrfTokenServiceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>xsrf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/xsrf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- New servlet for my REST API -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mobile-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mobile-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/restapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is the controller that should handle the requests:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app/restapi")
public class RestaurantController {

    class ReturnValue {
        public String str = "1337";
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
    public ReturnValue getTest() {
        return new ReturnValue();
    }
}
```

The problem is that requesting `http://localhost:8080/app/restapi/test` gives me just:

```
16:14:22.497 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'mobile-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/app/restapi/test]
16:14:22.497 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /test
16:14:22.497 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/test]
16:14:22.497 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/restapi/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mobile-dispatcher'
16:14:22.497 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

and I don't know why. So: What am I doing wrong here and how can I make this work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you configured your servlet mapping like this

`<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mobile-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/restapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

This is the root url of your application. When you configure your RestController with `RequestMapping("/app/restapi")`, that means the controller will listen to http://domain/app/restapi/app/restapi.
Just remove the `("/app/restapi")` from your controller definition and you should be fine.

While starting, the Spring MVC framework should print the URL mappings that it listens to to the console, you should see the mapping of your controller there.